# Call list of functions in python3

Tags: python-3.x

The following works in python2 for calling the list of function objects stored in the functions list:

```
for f in functions:
    map(f, data)
```

What is the equivalent for python3 as the above doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`map`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) in Python 3 returns an iterator, that's why nothing happens when you just call it.

Since you apparently don't care about returned values, I think it's best to use an explicit loop:

```
for f in functions:
    for d in data:
       f(d)
```

If you actually *do* store the results in Python2:

```
for f in functions:
    a = map(f, data)
```

then you could to change it to

```
for f in functions:
    a = list(map(f, data))
```

But I'd advise against using a list if you don't actually need the return values. It takes extra time and memory to build them and discard them right away.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a nested list comprehension:

```
[[f(d) for d in data] for f in functions]
```

Or just evaluate the map object, e.g. by converting it to a list:

```
list(map(f, data))
```

Comment: Because your advice is horrible. You're suggesting to make a nested list of `None`s and immediately get rid of it.

Comment: @BlaXpirit How is this horrible? First, this is *exactly* what `map(f, data)` does in python2 if you don't use the return value (except for the outer list). Second, the memory needed is very small (<100kb for 10k lists of 1k `None`s as reported by `getsizeof`), and as you said it is immediately available for gc. The time overhead of the lists shouldn't be significant, and because of the implicit loops it might even be faster than two explicit ones. So as long as OP doesn't need to process millions of data points with hundreds of functions, or has only 4k RAM, this answer should work wery well.